# Questions about Stiefel Manifold Dynamics

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I'm trying to read 'Multivariate Regression via Stiefel Manifold Constraints' (by G¨okhan H. Bakır, Arthur Gretton, Matthias Franz, and Bernhard Sch¨olkopf) because I have a regression problem on Stiefel Manifold.

I have some Linear Algebra background but not so much in differential geometry so there are a few points I'm stuck at, such as in Section 3.1 (Dynamics on Stiefel Manifold).

If we take a matrix $V$ in the Stiefel Manifold that depends on a parameter $t$, and we take the derivative of $I = V(t)^{\top}V$, we get $0 = Z(t)^{\top} + Z(t)$ with :

$Z(t) = V(t)^{\top}(\frac{d}{dt}V(t))$ skew-symmetric

I have difficulties to understand how they get the expression for $Z$ with the constrained gradient :

\begin{pmatrix}
\hat{G}^{\top}V  & -(\hat{G}^{\top}V_{\perp})^{\top}\\ 
\hat{G}^{\top}V_{\perp} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
with $\hat{G}$ being the constrained gradient defined by $\hat{G} = G - VG^{\top}V$.

And why do we have to study the geodesics of the manifold when we want to optimize a loss function F that depends on $V$ (I don't understand what is this parameter $t$) ?

Can someone please help me understand these points ?

Thanks !

Comment: What are $Z$, $G$, $V$? You have to provide enough details so that someone can understand and answer the question without looking at the book.